# Issue with Data driven testing in robot framework

Tags: automated-testing, robotframework

I have written code using robot framework, to open a browser and enter the values in a fields, but what is happening, it is opening the browser and redirecting the URL, but it is not writing to the fields and it is throwing the error ( i have attached in the screenshot ).

Please find below to check for the code and please help me resolve this.

Here is my `tests.robot` :

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library
Resource  resource.robot

*** Variables ***

@{TEST_DATA} =  fname  lname  9734565432  abcdefgh@3
@{TEST_DATA1} =  lname  fname  8756454456  sadsadef#1

*** Test Cases ***

open linkedin
    [Tags]  linkedin
    open browser  about:blank  ${BROWSER}
    maximize browser window
    go to  ${URL}

add entries
    resource.FIRST_NAME  @{TEST_DATA}[0]
    resource.LAST_NAME  @{TEST_DATA}[4]
    resource.PHONE_NUMBER  @{TEST_DATA}[4]
    resource.PASSWORD  @{TEST_DATA}[4]

close Linkedin
    close all browsers
```

And here `resources.robot` :

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***
${BROWSER} =  gc
${URL} =  https://www.linkedin.com/
${FIRST_NAME} =  xpath=//*[@id="reg-firstname"]
${LAST_NAME} =  xpath=//*[@id="reg-lastname"]
${PHONE_NUMBER} =  xpath=//*[@id="reg-email"]
${PASSWORD} =  xpath=//*[@id="reg-password"]



*** Keywords ***

FIRST_NAME
    input text  ${FIRST_NAME}


LAST_NAME
    input text  ${LAST_NAME}


PHONE_NUMBER
    input text  ${PHONE_NUMBER}

PASSWORD
    input text  ${PASSWORD}
```

Error Snap :

[image: Image showing the Error]

Answer (score 3):

The error should be very self-explanatory: you are passing an argument to the keyword `FIRST_NAME` ("got 1"), but that keyword doesn't take an argument ("expected 0").

To define your keyword to take an argument use `[Arguments]` to list the arguments that your keyword accepts. For example:

```
FIRST_NAME
    [Arguments]  ${FIRST_NAME}
    input text  ${FIRST_NAME}
```

For more information see [User Keyword Arguments](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#user-keyword-arguments) in the [robot framework user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html):

> The syntax is such that first the [Arguments] setting is given and then argument names are defined in the subsequent cells. Each argument is in its own cell, using the same syntax as with variables. The keyword must be used with as many arguments as there are argument names in its signature. The actual argument names do not matter to the framework, but from users' perspective they should be as descriptive as possible. It is recommended to use lower-case letters in variable names, either as ${my_arg}, ${my arg} or ${myArg}.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Input Text](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Input%20Text) Keyword definition

```
Input Text  locator, text
```

**Types the given text into text field identified by locator.**

So your as per it you need to pass the locator and text to the Input Text keyword, so in your above code you need to pass argument for text as you are using locator in the same file, You need to refactor resource.robot file as below,

resource.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library
Library    BuiltIn    

*** Variables ***
${BROWSER} =  gc
${URL} =  https://www.linkedin.com/
${FIRST_NAME} =  xpath=//*[@id="reg-firstname"]
${LAST_NAME} =  xpath=//*[@id="reg-lastname"]
${PHONE_NUMBER} =  xpath=//*[@id="reg-email"]
${PASSWORD} =  xpath=//*[@id="reg-password"] 

*** Keywords ***
 FIRST_NAME
    [Arguments]    ${TEST_DATA}
    Input Text    ${FIRST_NAME}    ${TEST_DATA}

 LAST_NAME
    [Arguments]    ${TEST_DATA}
    Input Text     ${LAST_NAME}    ${TEST_DATA}

 PHONE_NUMBER
     [Arguments]    ${TEST_DATA}
    Input Text    ${PHONE_NUMBER}    ${TEST_DATA}   

 PASSWORD
     [Arguments]    ${TEST_DATA}
    Input Text    ${PASSWORD}    ${TEST_DATA}
```